# Quelle est l’étymologie de ce mot « carabistouille » ?

Tags: étymologie, belgique

Tout ce que je sais de ce [mot](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/carabistouille) est qu'il est un *belgicisme* signifiant [calembredaine](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/calembredaine/12306), c’est-à-dire, une histoire absurde ou une sottise monumentale.

Mais je voudrais savoir aussi d’où vient ce mot dont la sonorité me semble si drôle et si amusant. (Ce mot me semble avoir une nature imitative, comme celle d'une onomatopée).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je n'avais jamais entendu le mot (je ne suis pas Belge) mais il me fait tout de suite penser à *carabinade*.

Une *carabinade*, ou *blague de carabin*, est une farce, une plaisanterie, en général de mauvais goût ou paillarde, qui tire son nom des *carabins*, nom familier donné aux étudiants en médecine.

Le suffixe -ouille donne « [une note plaisante, populaire, argotique, diminutive voire affectueuse à un mot](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ouille) ». La connotation « affectueuse » diminue la portée du mot, une *carabistouille* serait un peu moins de mauvais goût qu'une *blague de carabin*.

**Origine de carabin :**
*Carabin* est apparu au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle pour désigner un soldat de cavalerie légère (origine incertaine, peut-être du moyen-français *(e)scarabin* « ensevelisseur de pestiférés », l'expression *carabin de Saint-Côme* s'appliquant à un chirurgien. L'évolution sémantique s'expliquerait par la réputation des soldats dits *carabins* de faire rapidement mourir leurs patients. Le mot s'est diffusé au sens « d'étudiants en médecine » (source : *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld A.Rey).

Comment: C'est très, très intéressant. Et ces carabins dont vous parlez, ces étudiants en médecine, étaient-ils si drôles qu'ils étaient devenus renommés pour leur blagues ? Ce que je ne peux pas comprendre est la connexion entre eux et les blagues en général.

Comment: @user26328 Les étudiants en médecine sont réputés pour faire des blagues, je ne pense pas que ce soit spécifique à la France. Quand on étudie la médecine on voit des choses parfois dure à supporter psychologiquement et l'humour et les blagues, même mauvais, sont une façon de faire face aux cadavres à disséquer et autres horreurs. Je peux ajouter l'étymologie du mot carabin si tu veux.

Comment: « Depuis le début des études médicales, l’humour envahit le quotidien des médecins que ce soit dans les couloirs de l’hôpital ou sur les bancs de la faculté. Il permet de se dire des choses qui ne se diraient pas autrement.  » Début introductif d'une thèse : [Représentations sociales de la profession médicale au XXIe siècle véhiculées par la blague médicale : enquête auprès des médecins](https://dumas.ccsd.cnrs.fr/dumas-01103955/document).

Comment: C'est tout clair maintenant. Vous êtes un très bon / une très bonne éducateur / éducatrice de la langue français. J’apprécie beaucoup votre aide. (Et j'aime bien de parler et d’écrire en cette langage si belle...)

Comment: [Astérix chez les Belges](https://www.babelio.com/livres/Goscinny-Asterix-tome-24--Asterix-chez-les-Belges/14015/critiques#B_CRI394968)

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, the following “answer” as a whole and most of its individual parts might serve as prime examples of “des carabistrouilles”:

---

Although the accepted answer (resemblance to/possible derivative of *carabinade*) is very logical and **extremely likely to be correct**, there is a possible significance in the last two syllables of the cool word at issue (thanks for sharing it) that struck me as worthy of mention.

According to *TLFi/CNRTL*, the word [“bistouille”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bistouille) (which is letter-for-letter the last two syllables of your word)  can mean either cheap brandy (=“Mauvaise eau de vie")  or coffee laced with brandy (or depending, I suppose, on how you care to see and/or taste things, “Brandy laced with coffee”) (=“Café additionné d'eau de vie”).

The “coffee/brandy laced with brandy/coffee” sense is specifically listed as a regionalism from the French Department (le Nord/59) having the longest common border with Belgium,  and the entry’s etymology/history section seems to imply that even the “cheap brandy” sense originated in the “59.”

All of this to say primarily that there appears to be a Belgian (or at least a northern French) connection between the last two syllables of your word and the notion of cheap and/or laced brandy.

Admittedly, however, this connection explains neither the first two syllables (“cara”) nor how or why “cara” + “bistrouille” could possibly mean “une histoire absurde ou une sottise monumentale.”

Alas, the only way for me to even try to explain those last crucial two issues requires pure (read: "far-fetched") speculation on my part, as follows:

In English, the idea of someone talking foolishly/spouting hogwash is sometimes related to/blamed on the affects of too much alcohol, which idea can be expressed as:

> That’s just the [rotgut] brandy talking.

English even has a word (i.e., [“moonshine,”](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/moonshine)) that directly connects, in that single word, the notions of both “illegal [homemade] whiskey” (granted, not necessarily of poor quality) and that of foolish talk or ‘”nonsense.”

Unfortunately (that is, for the purposes of this “answer”), this is a French forum, which makes the connection in English mentioned above irrelevant here, and what’s even more unfortunate is that finding an irrelevant English connection has failed (this time, for it often does work) to lead me to a relevant French connection between:

> “bistouille” (or any form of alcohol) and “une histoire absurde ou
>   une sottise monumentale,” ...

... except for the rather weak (albeit literal) one of:

> C’est le vin/l’alcool qui parle.

(And it wouldn't help my argument at all to mention [except here for the sake of honesty] that both French and English, via Latin, have the notion of there being “truth in wine” [*in vino veritas*], which clearly contradicts, not only the “alcohol=nonsense” connection that I’m trying desperately to make/find in French, but also the very one in English that I'm claiming does exist and relying on herein.)

Anyway, even if an idiomatic French connection between over imbibing and sometimes fabricating absurd/embellished stories could be made or found, that would still require the use of some pure “carabistouilles” (like the following three examples) to try to explain what the “cara” means or where it might come from (but having made it this far, here goes nothing):

> ?“**cara**[fon de]**bistrouille**//**cara**[fe de]**bistrouille**”? =
>   ?“[That’s] a pitcher’s worth/crock of moonshine/bulls^^t.” ?
>
> ?“**car**[a^]**bistrouille**”? (where “car”=“because/due to” [^but it
>   wouldn't account for the second "a"]) = ?“[That’s] due to the
>   moonshine//[That's] the moonshine talking.” ?
>
> ?"**carabistrouille**"? (where "cara" is a mispronunciation of "gare
>   à"/"watch out for") = ?"[Watch out for] the affects of moonshine."?

Comment: *Bistouille /bistrouille* (19th century) is well known in the north of France for bad liquor (any bad liquor), it comes form *bistrot*/ *bistroquet* (not as classy as a *café*, so supposed to sell cheap liquor)   and the etymology is strongly felt in he word.  And *touille* from *touiller* (mixed / blended).