# Typically French Behavior

Tags: expressions

*Franchouillardise*, selon [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/franchouillard/35028?q=franchouillard#34998), signifie

> Qui présente les défauts traditionnellement attribués au Français
>   moyen (en particulier chauvinisme, étroitesse d'esprit). (Populaire et
>   péjoratif)

Y-t-il un autre mot français qui signifie la même chose sans le sens péjoratif attribué au premier mot ?

Comment: Je ne vois pas comment un mot qui désigne les défauts de quelque chose peut ne pas être péjoratif.  Un synonyme de l'adjectif *franchouillard* est  [franco-français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-fran%C3%A7ais). Même si ce n'est pas  le mot que tu cherches, tu seras peut-être intéressé par le connaître. Le mot n'a pas toujours un sens péjoratif mais il peut l'être, par contre il est d'un niveau de langue plus élevé que *franchouillard*.

Comment: The accepted answer to your question about [the origins of the word “carabistouille”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25643) discusses the softening effect of ending words with “ouille,” so maybe this would be the case with *franchouille* (listed [here](http://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/dico-mot-definition/64248/franchouillard.php) as a synonym for *franchouillard*). However, considering that the “ouill[e]” is already part of the longer word in question (and is arguably not being added as a softening suffix to a shorter word), maybe this case is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il existe le nom [***francocentrisme***](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francocentrisme).

> Tendance, consciente ou non, à valoriser la manière de penser française et à l’étendre à la compréhension d’autres cultures. ([Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/francocentrisme))

Le terme n'est pas populaire, de style plus soutenu que *franchouillardise* mais de par son sens même l'emploi est le plus souvent péjoratif.

> Mais vous me permettrez de vous faire irrespectueusement remarquer, mesdames et messieurs les écrivains, que vous contribuez dans ce manifeste, avec toute l'autorité que votre talent confère à votre parole, à entretenir le plus grave des contresens sur la francophonie, en confondant francocentrisme et francophonie, en confondant exception culturelle et diversité culturelle. ([*Le Monde*,19/08/2007](http://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2007/03/19/la-francophonie-une-realite-oubliee-par-abdou-diouf_884956_3232.html))

> Les ravages du franco-centrisme ([*La Croix*,23/02/2009](http://www.la-croix.com/Archives/2009-02-23/Les-ravages-du-franco-centrisme-_NP_-2009-02-23-339595))

Il faut aussi considérer l'adjectif ***[franco-français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-fran%C3%A7ais)***, souvent utilisé pour décrire une attitude typiquement française, qui est synonyme de l'adjectif *franchouillard*, ce n'est pas un terme populaire, de style plus soutenu que *franchouillard* mais qui reste familier dans certains de ses emplois.

> Prostitution, l’apparition d’une traite franco-française ([La Croix](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francocentrisme), 24/05/2016)

→ Désigne ici un fait circonscrit à la France, l'emploi n'est pas péjoratif.

> Difficultés d’accès à la langue, prédominance d’une culture franco-française, image de la supériorité de notre modèle, les raisons sont multiples, mais cette suffisance constitue une véritable lacune... ([Informations sociales, revue des Caisse nationale d'allocations familiales, n° 150](https://www.cairn.info/revue-informations-sociales-2008-6-page-174.htm))

→ Ici l'emploi est péjoratif puisqu'il est utilisé pour déprécier la culture française.